# Time complexity of the method

Tags: java, time-complexity

My toString() method's time complexity is supposed to be `O(Row*Col)`. What I can see from the code is that there are two for-loops where one of them is running through the rows and the other one is running through the cols.

Does the declaration of String variables take a lot of time? I have written code but does it have that exact time complexity?

Comment: :) :) :) :) @TAsk, is there any way to shorten it ?? Can StringBuilder usage shorten it??

Comment: First of all, get rid of all the redundancy, like a switch with only one case.

Comment: @John That looks like the printing of a board (seen a lot of board questions on here lately). You don't build a string of the entire board in a `toString()` method. Create a method called `printBoard()` instead. `toString()` is for returning a string representation of the object, e.g. for debugging, so a return value of "board(10 x 15)" would be appropriate.

Comment: You could probably also gain a lot by using String.format

Comment: use something like `secondLine1 += "|" + "   ".subString(0,"   ".length() - temp.length()) +  temp;`. String.format is quite slow. Externalize this string "   "

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the complexity is O(Row*Col) or O(N) with N being the number of elements.

Declarations do not enter into the asymptotic running time, because these have constant time.

Comment: So, the `toString()` does have tha O(R*C) complexity, right? @popovitsj

Comment: Btw, @popovitsj, isnt O(R*C) equivalent to O(N^2) ? I have the nested loop in the code, isnt the time complexity O(N^2)  or O(R*C) ?

Comment: @John, it's equivalent to O(N^2) if R == C. It's often forgotten, but if you say a running time is O(N-something), you should always state what N stands for. In this case I would call this algorithm O(N) with N being the number of elements, and the number of elements can of course be calculated with `R*C`